# An exercise of Frobenius' Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an n-manifold such that $TM=E_1\oplus E_2$, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are involutive subbundle of $TM$. Show that there are subspaces $F_1$ and $F_2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n=F_1\oplus F_2$, and local charts $\phi:U\subset M\rightarrow V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $T\phi$ maps each fiber of $E_i$ onto $F_i$.

I don't know how to prove it rigorously using Frobenius' theorem, since I'm not sure if we can straighten out two foliations simultaneously.

Comment: Have you tried using two charts, each given by Frobenius, and then using appropriate subsets of each to give a new chart? All you need to do is check that it will in fact be a chart.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, surely I tried, I can find this subset, but the problem is how to write an explicit formula for the chart from the old ones such that the two foliations are both flat.

Comment: Use the ones whose level sets give you each of the foliations.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, this is the spirit of the proof, but I wish someone can give me a more detailed answer, or an explicit construction of the desired chart. Since, as I know, each chart can only flatten one foliation. Maybe I just lose some basic facts of this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $E_1$ has rank $n-k$ and $E_2$ has rank $k$. By involutivity, there are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^k,x^{k+1},\dots,x^n)$ and $(y^1,\dots,y^k,y^{k+1},\dots,y^n)$ so that $E_1 = \{dx^1=0, dx^2=0,\dots, dx^k=0\}$ and $E_2 = \{dy^{k+1}=0,\dots,dy^n=0\}$. I contend that $(x^1,\dots,x^k,y^{k+1},\dots,y^n)$ is the local coordinate system you seek. (You'll take $F_1=\{0\}\times\Bbb R^{n-k}$ and $F_2 = \Bbb R^k\times\{0\}\subset\Bbb R^n$.)

All that you really need to check here is that this is a bona fide coordinate system (i.e., a local diffeomorphism). But note that $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k\wedge dy^{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge dy^n \ne 0$. To see this, evaluate on $(v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n)$ where $v_1,\dots,v_k$ give a basis for $E_2$ and $v_{k+1},\dots,v_n$ give a basis for $E_1$. (Note that $dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^k(X_1,\dots,X_k)=0$ if and only if some linear combination of the $X_i$ is an element of $E_1$.)

Comment: I got it, thank u very much !!

Comment: You're welcome. When you're satisfied that you have no further questions, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't stay on the unanswered list. :)